# Displaying help text when the mouse is over pushbutton and lineedit in Qt

Tags: qt4

I have a pushbutton and a lineedit , and what i want is , when my mouse is over that pushbutton or lineedit a help text(the purpose of that pushbutton and lineedit) shall be shown besides the pushbutton or lineedit. Please give reply soon , i need it urgently .. Thankx in advance ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QWidget::whatsThis](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qwidget.html#whatsThis-prop), [QWidget::toolTip](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qwidget.html#toolTip-prop) or [QWidget::statusTip](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qwidget.html#statusTip-prop) does what you want, depending on your needs.

Comment: Could you pease give an example on how to implement QWhatsthis ?

Comment: myWidget->setWhatsThis( tr("blablabla").

Really man  - do try and read the manuals a little bit